# Custom date list in QDateEdit using pyqt

Tags: qt, pyqt

I am using QDateEdit widget to get the user selected date from the calender (popup). However, I want to allow the user to pick dates from a list of specific dates (highlighted on the calender) and not just any date. I see that using setMinimumDate and setMaximumDate the dates outside the  the specified range gets grayed out and hence cannot be selected -- this is exactly what I want but not for a range but for a list of specific dates.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Subclass [QCalendarWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcalendarwidget.html) and use [QDateTimeEdit::setCalendarWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdatetimeedit.html#setCalendarWidget) to set it as the widget to be used for the calendar pop-up.

Comment: Even if I use QCalendarWidget, how do I get it to show a list of specific dates.

Comment: I cannot give you an example. It's difficult, but i believe doable. Do `git://gitorious.org/qt/qt.git` ans study code in `src/gui/widgets/qcalendarwidget.cpp` to see how the authors did it.